# Controller, View, Delegation - how to design properly

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

Searched other questions but still no answer ...
Need some advise.
I am porting my code from another platform to iOS.
I have an MVC backbone in C++ : 
CData for model. 
CController for controller.

- CController creates an instance of CData
- CController creates an instance of CView
- CController inherits from CNotifications abstract
- CController passes "this" to constructor of CView
- CView expects CNotifications* in the  constructor and this is how the CView can call the controller back on some important events without actually be aware of the CController itself

On Windows CView would simply access GDI to draw whatever was needed.

Now I am porting all this to iOS. CData and CController are completely platform independent so all clear. I was going to just re-implement the CView over iOS. And this is where the problem is.

At the start I wanted my ViewController of ios ( the owner of the xib ) just to inherit from CView and implement all CController needs. But then I noticed that there is no multiple inheritance in Obj-C and the ViewController already inherits from UIViewController.

So it seems I need to implement CView in such a way that it has a pointer to ViewController( the owner of the xib ).

And the question is : how to nicely pass to CView a pointer to ViewController ?

I planned the ApplicationDelegate to create the CController which would create the CData and the the CView. I dont want CController to receive a pointer to ViewController and then pass this pointer further to CView - I want CController stay portable...

There are all sorts of things coming into head but I was hoping to get here a widely-acceptable approach

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since `CView` is one of your own classes, can you not base it on `UIView` instead of `NSObject`?

Comment: UIViewController and UIView are two different things in iOS, they entract, but UIViewController doesn't inherit from UIView. You may want to take time to get a better understanding of how these work in iOS paradigm, before rushing into porting your C++ codebase

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - CView is my C++ class and it does not inherit from anything. Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: @ChrisChen - It was a typo. ViewController inherits from UIViewController indeed. I've edited the question. I am pretty new to iOS and may lack some knowledge. Could you please point to an article which could help this specific subj? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this by simply having the ViewController creating both the Controller and the View of my bussines logic and passing the View to the Controller